Is Cassandra certified on KVM?
I run Cassandra 4.1.3 inside OpenNMS Horizon 30.0.4; we run the solution on vms virtualized with VMware ESXi on Ubuntu 20.0.4 LTS; we were asked by the customer to migrate the solution from VMware to KVM.
I could not find any reference to KVM virtualization; is Cassandra certified on Kvm? If not, is it because it's totally independent on the virtualization env on which it's installed?
Thanks in adavnce for you help.
Daniele

The Apache Cassandra project does not perform any kind of certification process of any virtualisation platform or technology.
Cassandra operates independently of the operating system instance (OSI). It can run on most Linux OSIs, virtualised or otherwise.
If you have any concerns around deploying on KVM environments then you should conduct your own extensive testing with production-like workloads. Cheers!
